# All Diagonal elements of a NXN matrix without using numpy in python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

Trying to get all the diagonal elements of a NXN matrix without using numpy,

This is different from [Get diagonal without using numpy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447210/get-diagonal-without-using-numpy-in-python)

Please don't mark as duplicate.

Here is my snippet using two iteration, it will print all the diagonal element from (0,0) to (n,n). Could some one help me in improving my iteration process or any recursive way to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

matrix = [[1,2,3,4], 
          [2,3,4,5], 
          [3,4,5,6], 
          [4,5,6,7]] 

def get_matrix_diagonal(m): 
    col = len(m) 
    result = list() 
    row = 0 
    for c in range(col): 
        position = list() 
        position.append([row,c]) 
        if c > 0: 
            i = c 
            while i > 0: 
                x = i - 1 
                y = c - i + 1 
                position.append([y,x]) 
                i -= 1 
        result.append(position) 
    row = row + 1 
    cc = c 
    for i in range(row,col): 
        position = list() 
        y = i 
        x = c 
        position.append([y,x]) 
        j = x - y 
        while j > 0: 
            y = c - j + 1 
            x = cc - y + 1 
            position.append([y,x]) 
            j -= 1 
        cc += 1
        result.append(position)
    return result

for ls in get_matrix_diagonal(matrix):
    for co in ls:
        x,y = co[0],co[1],
        print matrix[x][y],
    print
```

Output:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6
7
```

Comment: I didn't vote for close, but really this would be better asked on codereview I think

Comment: Ok will do that next time thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3,4], 
...           [2,3,4,5], 
...           [3,4,5,6], 
...           [4,5,6,7]] 
>>> N = 4
>>> [[matrix[y-x][x] for x in range(N) if 0<=y-x<N] for y in range(2*N-1)]
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6], [7]]
```

Comment: WoW, this is sweet... @gnibbler could you help me with recursion or is it possible to do with recursion ?

Comment: To solve with recursion, you'll need to find a way to break an NxN matrix  into a smaller problem using an MxM matrix, so M<N

Comment: Ok I ll try that, but i was not sure about the base case.

Comment: @yopy, the base case can be either N=1(trivial) or N=0(also trivial)

Answer (score 2):

Here an recursive approach supposing your matrix is square:

```
def diagonals(m):
    if len(m) == 1: return m
    d = [[]] + diagonals([r[1:] for r in m[:-1]]) + [[]]
    r = [r[0] for r in m] + m[-1][1:]
    return [[r] + d for r, d in zip(r,d)]
```

Comment: AWESOME, thank you so much. it works but i need to read to understand :)

Comment: Basically, each recursion removes the left most column and the bottom most line.